# Filtering db table by date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My goals is to make filter for loading posts from 1 week ago, 1 month ago and two inputs from date from and date to ( if one of them is empty to be filled with current date( y-m-d h:m:s ) format

This is all i tried and could have made it to work, every answer is much appreciated, thank you

Tl:dr
Select filter for week ago, month ago
From date - to date ( if one of those is empty then use current date )

Index.php

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");  
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_order ORDER BY order_id desc";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Ajax PHP MySQL Date Range Search using jQuery DatePicker</title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:900px;">  
                <h2 align="center">Ajax PHP MySQL Date Range Search using jQuery DatePicker</h2>  
                <h3 align="center">Order Data</h3><br />  
                <div class="col-md-3">  
                     <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" class="form-control" placeholder="From Date" />  
                </div>  
                <div class="col-md-3">  
                     <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date" />  
                </div>  
                <div class="col-md-5">  
                     <input type="button" name="filter" id="filter" value="Filter" class="btn btn-info" />  
                </div>  
                <div style="clear:both"></div>                 
                <br />  
                <div id="order_table">  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th width="5%">ID</th>  
                               <th width="30%">Customer Name</th>  
                               <th width="43%">Item</th>  
                               <th width="10%">Value</th>  
                               <th width="12%">Order Date</th>  
                          </tr>  
                     <?php  
                     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                     {  
                     ?>  
                          <tr>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["order_id"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["order_customer_name"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["order_item"]; ?></td>  
                               <td>$ <?php echo $row["order_value"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["order_date"]; ?></td>  
                          </tr>  
                     <?php  
                     }  
                     ?>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
      $(document).ready(function(){  
           $.datepicker.setDefaults({  
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'   
           });  
           $(function(){  
                $("#from_date").datepicker();  
                $("#to_date").datepicker();  
           });  
           $('#filter').click(function(){  
                var from_date = $('#from_date').val();  
                var to_date = $('#to_date').val();  
                if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')  
                {  
                     $.ajax({  
                          url:"filter.php",  
                          method:"POST",  
                          data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},  
                          success:function(data)  
                          {  
                               $('#order_table').html(data);  
                          }  
                     });  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     alert("Please Select Date");  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 </script>
```

And filter.php

```
<?php  
 //filter.php  
 if(isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"]))  
 {  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");  
      $output = '';  
      $query = "  
           SELECT * FROM tbl_order  
           WHERE order_date BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."'  
      ";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      $output .= '  
           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  
                     <th width="5%">ID</th>  
                     <th width="30%">Customer Name</th>  
                     <th width="43%">Item</th>  
                     <th width="10%">Value</th>  
                     <th width="12%">Order Date</th>  
                </tr>  
      ';  
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
      {  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
           {  
                $output .= '  
                     <tr>  
                          <td>'. $row["order_id"] .'</td>  
                          <td>'. $row["order_customer_name"] .'</td>  
                          <td>'. $row["order_item"] .'</td>  
                          <td>$ '. $row["order_value"] .'</td>  
                          <td>'. $row["order_date"] .'</td>  
                     </tr>  
                ';  
           }  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td colspan="5">No Order Found</td>  
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }  
      $output .= '</table>';  
      echo $output;  
 }  
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this to make sure that you are getting the correct format from your datepicker:

```
$("#from_date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
```

Make PHP variables to use in your query for the date:

```
 $fromDate = !empty($_POST['from_date']) ? "'".mysqli_escape_string($_POST["from_date"])."'" : "CURDATE()";
 $toDate = !empty($_POST["to_date"]) ? "'".mysqli_escape_string($_POST["to_date"])."'" : "CURDATE()";

 $query = 
"SELECT * 
   FROM tbl_order  
  WHERE order_date 
BETWEEN $fromDate
    AND $toDate";
```

NOTE: You should also add some logic in there to make sure that the from_date does not end up being before the to_date.

NOTE 2: This answer is making the assumption that you have not set up PDO. Always make sure to avoid SQL injection attacks in some way. Any values coming from the front end are unsafe and subject to SQL injection. PDO would be preferable, but escaping will work.

Answer (score -1):

You can try casting your $_POST using CAST function to convert values to date.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_order
WHERE order_date 
    BETWEEN CAST('".$_POST["from_date"]."' AS DATE) 
    AND CAST('".$_POST["to_date"]."' AS DATE)";
```

You can read about it on [MySQLTutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cast/) .

Also I recommend you to escape variables when working with database :-) Always expect user is up to no good.